# Hibernate doesn't seem to be scanning for @Entity @Table

Tags: spring, hibernate

I've got two Spring Hibernate modules that I'm trying to combine. They have separate application contexts. In one hibernate uses xml mapping files while in the second module annotations are used to map the hibernate db tables.

Both modules seem to be scanned ok (service beans seem to be injected ok) except for the hibernate table scanning in the second table. One table occurs twice -- once in the xml mapping files and once in annotations but in different java packages with separated package scanning.

When I try to access the second module's table class in a hibernate select I get:

MappingException: Unknown entity: msg.entity: message

I tried substituting another annotated table entity in the hibernate query to check where the problem was mapping to the same table but I get the same MappingException so it seems like the problem is that hibernate is just not picking up any @Entity @Table annotations in the second module. But I tested this module on it's own and all the annotations did get picked up ok.

Could it be that the hibernate session factory is somehow being carried over from the calling module and masking the second module's session factory and its associated list of entities? Yet I'm not in a transaction in the calling method.

```
      <context:component-scan base-package="msg"/>

      <bean id="sessionFactory" 
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceJmsMod"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="msg.entity"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
        </props>
    </property>        
    </bean>

   Thanks for any help
```